# How CrudRepository deals with DB Connection from ConnectionPool

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, tomcat-jdbc, spring-data-commons

I can't find any default implementation class for spring-data-commons `crudrepository` interface. We always implement `CustomRepository extends CrudRepository<T, ID>` and then `@Autowire CustomRepository customRepository` in the service class to call `customRepository.save(s)`..which always works. 
I'd like to understand the low level details associated with any crudrepository method e.g. `save(S)`;

1. When is the connection to underlying database opened or closed?
2. How the transaction boundaries are defined?
3. How does it work with connection-pool? 
   Any pointers to the right resources would be really helpful.Please feel free to point me out if I'm missing something silly...

Comment: The connection/session is, as with regular Spring code, opened when the transaction starts. Generally that is done with a `@Transactional` on the service level. When transaction finishes the session is closed and connection is also closed (with a connection pool this results in returning it to the pool).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks! Will it be possible to guide me to the default implementation class? `SimpleJpaRepository` is default impl for `JpaRepository`... is there a default impl class for `CrudRepository` also?

Comment: The `SimpleJpaRepository` it is.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks! So the default implementation of `CrudRepository` is JPA compliant and Hibernate is the default JPA Provider.